# Compile error Vector Sort and Union

Tags: c++, vector

I have a simple program that generates two points (consisting of vector of integers) and find the union of two vectors of two different points. But there are some strange compile errors that I am not able to figure it out.

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::set_union, std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;
struct Point {
    std::vector<uint32_t> vec;
};

vector<uint32_t> inter_section( const Point& p1, const Point& p2 )
{
    vector<uint32_t> v3;

    sort(p1.vec.begin(), p1.vec.end());
    sort(p2.vec.begin(), p2.vec.end());

    set_intersection(p1.vec.begin(),p1.vec.end(),p2.vec.begin(),p2.vec.end(),back_inserter(v3));

    return v3;
}


int main () {
  Point p1, p2;
  vector<uint32_t> res = inter_section(p1, p2);

  return 0;
}
```

The compile error is

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/algorithm:62:0,
                 from testUnion.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::__insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int> >]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h:2211:62:   required from ‘void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h:5462:47:   required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int> >]’
testUnion.cpp:18:38:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h:2142:17: error: assignment of read-only location ‘__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator*<const unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int> >()’
        *__first = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__val);
```

Comment: this line `set_intersection(p1.vec..begin(),p1.vec.end(),p2.vec.begin(),p2.vec.end(),back_inserter(v3));` you have 2 dots for `p1.vec..begin()` and `p1.vec..end()`

Comment: I guess the `intersection` function should be named `set_intersection`

Comment: Maybe you should consider to use a DevEnv like CLion to avoid those kind of problems...

Comment: To be clear, Stack Overflow will not tolerate being treated as a replacement for a moment's thought or any debugging effort on your own. These errors are absolutely trivial.

Comment: It must be a trap. OP just fixed two of the typos in the question via an edit, but not the same typo _directly on the line below_.

Comment: Sorry, the errors are not because of typos.

Comment: Then give us the errors and copy and paste the [mcve] the errors come from into the question.  Asking us to debug code that doesn't represent your actual code is pointless.

Comment: The compile error is due to the sort() function. I am sorry, I edited the portion of my long code and some typos were there.

Comment: You're passing your struct that contain the vectors as const refs but then calling `sort` this won't work, remove the `const` qualifier

Comment: That did a trick. Sorry for my dumb question. Thanks a lot @EdChum

Comment: @Walter - I disagree.  It's a simple cause, but the reasoning of how to go from error message to a diagnosis and fix is certainly educational.  I'm sure others have been surprised at getting a `const_iterator` when they expected ordinary iterator.

Answer (score 3):

## Analysis

In C++ prior to Concepts, compilation errors from template methods can be hard to follow to their origins.  This should improve in future C++, but for now, we need to have skills in interpreting them.

The first place to start is the **`required from here`** which identifies which source code line is the problem (here, a call to `std::sort`), and the following line, which shows the ultimate action that violates the program semantics: **`assignment of read-only location`**.

Why is it a read-only location?  Well, looking back at the expansions, we have a `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int> >`.  That's the internal representation of a `std::vector<uint32_t>::const_iterator`; the important thing to note is `const unsigned int*` rather than just `unsigned int*` as in the corresponding mutable iterator.

Why did we get a `const_iterator`?  The `begin()` method of a vector is overloaded; we get a `const_iterator` back if the vector is const.  The same is true of the `end()` method.

Why is the vector constant?  It came from a (reference to a) `const Point` object.

## Summary of the cause

The function takes `p1` and `p2` as references to `const Point` objects.

Within a `const Point`, the `vec` member is a `const std::vector<uint32_t>`.

The `begin()` and `end()` methods of a `const std::vector<uint32_t>` both return a `std::vector<uint32_t>::const_iterator`.

You can't write through a `const_iterator`.

## Solutions

If you are willing to modify the objects to which `p1` and `p2` refer, you could pass them as references to modifiable `Point`:

```
std::vector<uint32_t> inter_section(Point& p1, Point& p2)
{
    std::sort(p1.vec.begin(), p1.vec.end());
    std::sort(p2.vec.begin(), p2.vec.end());

    std::vector<uint32_t> v3;
    std::set_intersection(p1.vec.begin(), p1.vec.end(),
                          p2.vec.begin(), p2.vec.end(),
                          std::back_inserter(v3));

    return v3;
}
```

Otherwise, you'll need to work on a copy of the vector.  You could pass `p1` and `p2` by value, but in general, you should just copy what you need (in this case their `vec` members) into appropriate locals within your function:

```
std::vector<uint32_t> inter_section(const Point& p1, const Point& p2)
{
    auto v1 = p1.vec;
    auto v2 = p2.vec;
    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

    std::vector<uint32_t> v3;
    std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
                          v2.begin(), v2.end(),
                          std::back_inserter(v3));
    return v3;
}
```

---

## Complete program

Here's a fixed version of the program, minus the unused headers and the (brittle) `using namespace std;`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

struct Point {
    std::vector<uint32_t> vec{};
};

std::vector<uint32_t> inter_section(const Point& p1, const Point& p2)
{
    auto v1 = p1.vec;
    auto v2 = p2.vec;
    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

    std::vector<uint32_t> v3;
    std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
                          v2.begin(), v2.end(),
                          std::back_inserter(v3));
    return v3;
} 

int main () {
    Point p1, p2;
    std::vector<uint32_t> res = inter_section(p1, p2);
}
```